# Can AS3 Shared Objects be accessed by more than one application?

Tags: actionscript-3, shared-objects

I'm trying to access a shared object created by one flash application from another flash application. Is this possible? If so, what do I need to do?

If not, are there any other ways to share the information between the applications?

Any help you can give is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone else looking for the answer, multiple applications CAN access a single swf. You just have to be sure you use the optional localPath argument on your getLocal method call. eg:

```
var mySharedObject:SharedObject = getLocal("sharedobject", "/");
```

We used /, but you can use any directory you'd like. Just make sure all your applications use the same one.

Answer (score 0):

Well yes there are many other ways, you can save to a text file, an xml file or a database for instance.

As for SharedObjects , check this article

http://jaycsantos.com/flash/the-trick-to-using-sharedobject/

Don't forget that SharedObjects are similar to cookies there will be a few limitations , same browser, memory limit etc...

Comment: The applications are both run locally, and unfortunately, don't seem to support reading to text, xml or databases. We did look into that earlier, believe me.

Comment: well, if they are flash application , of course they support it. what makes you say they don't?

Comment: You would need PHP for this: http://www.actionscript.org/resources/articles/141/1/Introduction-to-Flash-and-PHP/Page1.html

Comment: That link is great, thank you. It might just have helped solve our problem.